# React-Native infinite loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I am trying to get data from my `firebase-firestore` I an showing a loading state to wait for the data to load however when it does load it keeps returning the firestore data infinite times. Please may someone help me.

This is my code `Paper` is just a custom component

```
import Paper from '../Components/Paper'
import firebase from 'firebase'
import { useState } from 'react'

const Home = (props) => {
    const renderMealItem = (itemData) =>{
        return (
            <Paper 
                title={itemData.item.name}
                serves={itemData.item.servings}
                time={itemData.item.time}
                image={itemData.item.imageUri}

            />
        )
    }
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)
    const [all, setAll] = useState([])
    
    useEffect(() => {
        setLoading(true)
        checkReturn()
        getUser()
        
    },[])

    const checkReturn = () => {
        if(all !== undefined){
            setLoading(false)
        }
    }

    const getUser = async() => {
        try {
            await firebase.firestore()
            .collection('Home')
            .get()
                .then(querySnapshot => {
                    querySnapshot.docs.forEach(doc => {
                        setAll(JSON.stringify(doc.data()));
                    });
                });
                    
        }catch(err){
            console.log(err)
        }
        
    }
    return(
        <View style={styles.flatContainer}>
            <FlatList
                data={all}
                keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
                renderItem={renderMealItem}/> 
        </View>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`useEffect` without second parameter will get executes on each update.

```
    useEffect(() => {
        setLoading(true)
        checkReturn()
        getUser()
        
    })
```

so this will set the loading and tries to get the user. and when the data comess from server, it will get runned again.

So you should change it to : `useEffect(() => {...}, [])` to only get executed on mount phase(start).

Update: you should check for return on every update, not only at start. so change the code to:

```
    useEffect(() => {
        setLoading(true)
        getUser()  
    }, [])
    useEffect(() => {
        checkReturn()
    })
```

Ps: there is another issue with your code as well:

```
querySnapshot.docs.forEach(doc => {
  setAll(JSON.stringify(doc.data()));
});
```

maybe it should be like :

```
setAll(querySnapshot.docs.map(doc => JSON.stringify(doc.data())));
```

Comment: Hey thanks for your quick response however even after trying the empty argument it's still returning infinitely

Comment: Hey thanks , also I am getting the error `Setting a timer for a long period of time, i.e. multiple minutes, is a performance and correctness issue on Android` Based on my code would you know why it is infinity returning this error

Comment: @DilhanBhagat did the prev issue fixed? i'm not sure what's this message talking about since currently you don't have any timer in your code.

Comment: Yeah It fixed it in away but for some reason the `FlatList` is still displaying infinite blank renders of the `Paper` component even though from concole logging there's only one `Object` returned from `firestore`. Please help me out if been getting this error for a while. Thank you in advanced

Comment: @DilhanBhagat maybe you didn't noticed the updated version of my answer. (Ps part)

Answer (score 0):

Try passing an empty array as an argument to `useEffect` like so:

```
   useEffect(() => {
        setLoading(true)
        checkReturn()
        getUser()
        
    }, [])
```

Comment: Hey thanks for your quick response however even after trying the empty argument it's still returning infinitely

Comment: @DilhanBhagat What is the `checkReturn` function doing?

Comment: Just updated the code with the function . sorry I forgot to include it.